# Equilibrium and Stability of Nonlinear Interactions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, applications, biology

Examine the nonlinear model:

$$\triangle x_t = rx_t(1-\frac{x_t}{K})-sx_ty_t$$
$$\triangle y_t = -dy_t+\epsilon x_ty_t$$

Find the equilibrium and their stability. Here all the parameters are positive.

The first step is to find the stability, and then set up a jacobian matrix to identify if these are stable or unstable.

Step one: find the equilibrium: so we do this by setting both equations equal to zero.

$$0 = rx(1-\frac{x}{k})-sxy$$
$$0 =x(r(1-\frac{x}{k})-sy)$$ 
This is the first equation setting equal to zero
The next equation setting equal to zero is
$$0=y(-d+\epsilon x)$$
By inspection, one equilibrium is at $x_t=y_t=0$

Now there are two other equilibrium.
from $0=y(-d+ \epsilon x)$ we get two options to plug into the first equation. We can either plug in zero for $y$ or we can plug in $-d+ \epsilon x$
Doing this we get $$x(r(1-\frac{x}{k})-s(0) \rightarrow x(r-\frac{x}{k})=0$$ The solution we get is $$x=k$$ and this is our second equilibrium.

The third equilibrium we get is when we have $y=-d+ \epsilon x$ plugging this back into the $x$ equation, we get $$x(r(1-\frac{x}{k})-S(-d + \epsilon x)$$

Now we have to solve for when this equation equals zero. This is where I am stuck, I know it is just algebra.

Comment: What is $\triangle$? The derivative with respect to $t$? // Why do you have a problem computing the Jacobian matrix at "the other equilibrium"? What did you find for this matrix?

Comment: "The third equilibrium we get is when we have $y=-d+ \epsilon x$" No. Please revise this step.

Answer (score 0):

1. Factor the $x_t$ out of the first equation.
2. Factor the $y_t$ out of the second equation.
3. You get 0 in the second equation if $x_t=\frac{d}{\epsilon}$. Plug that value of $x_t$ into the parenthetical of first equation and solve for the value of $y_t$ which makes that parenthetical zero.